# When using Interfaces causes repetition but using abstract class causes extraneous attributes

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, interface, composition

I currently have an abstract class `MyList`.

```
abstract class MyList<T> {
    public allItems: Array<Array<T>> = []
    public currentPageItems: Array<T> = []
    public currentPage: 

    private setupPagination(data: Array<T>) {
        //implementation
    }

    private resetPagination() {
        //implementation
    }

    private delete(id: number) {
        //implementation
    }

    //more functions and other abstract functions
}
```

`MyList` supports pagination, search filtering, delete, and things had been going well until I realized that I need a class that needs all of `MyList`'s method except `delete(id: number)` (let's call this class `ListX`).

I know I could've use interface composition by re-implementing `MyList` as multiple interfaces (Favor composition over inheritance), but all of the other classes that inherit `MyList` except `ListX` have identical implementation. By turning it into interfaces I would need to re-implement identical methods in all of the other inheriting classes, which is against DRY (don't repeat yourself).

I often come across the trend of people saying "favor composition over inheritance" and to use interfaces, but what would you do when you have similar classes that have really identical implementations? It would make more sense to just generalize them as an abstract class because interfaces will only make you repeat yourself. But again, what will happen when you found outlier case where a class needs only a part of the said abstract class?

Comment: You've encountered one of the challenges with OOP and its hierarchies.  Although I don't have the time atm to flesh out an answer, I will point you in the direction of Traits and Mixins.  I'm not sure if they are a feature in Typescript, but they do provide one solution to the problem you've noticed.

One 'solution' (not really) that comes to mind is throwing a IllegalOperationException, or something similar, for that one special case where delete is not applicable.